# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

i installed pillow from cmd : 
**pip install pillow**
and after that i went to import it :
**from PIL import Image**
but i found  an error : 
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'**
please help !!

Comment: Are you using an environment like Anaconda? The installation ended without errors message?

Comment: Have you installed Pillow in your enviroment ?
pip install Pillow

Comment: @PauloHenrique yes i did !! iam so sad the error made me upset

Comment: @powerPixie i don't use anaconda i have visual studio and IDLE 3.7 64 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I tried Installing Pillow from my 'manages packages' in my thonny  and my problem was solved.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).